# AngularJS ng-option inside ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Very simple problem, but not sure how to solve it

I have ng-repeat, that iterate model video.

the model has a chosen value and I want to see it in the dropdown list:

```
<div data-ng-repeat="singleVideo in model.videos">
    {{singleVideo}}<select data-ng-model="singleVideo.name" ng-options="item.name for item in videoList"></select>
</div>
```

this is the video model:

```
$scope.model = {
                 videos:[
                    {id:1,name:"VIDEO_ONE"},
                    {id:2,name:"VIDEO_TWO"}
                ]
            }
```

this is the videoList item:

```
$scope.videoList = [
                {id:1,name:"VIDEO_ONE"},
                {id:2,name:"VIDEO_TWO"},
                {id:3,name:"VIDEO_Three"}
            ];
```

simply I expect to see that the first dropdown value will be set to VIDEO_ONE
the second dropdown value will be set to VIDEO_TWO.

Currently the dropdown is empty.

How can I achieve that?

[image: This is the expected result, currently i'm getting the dropdown boxes empty]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You just need to set a value for the ng-options with `item.id as item.name for item in videoList`. see code below.

(i set the **id** as the value, since i think it's better suited. somewhere you also need to update your `name` attribute according to **id**. or vice verca. your choice.)

```js
angular.module('testapp', [])
.controller('appCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.model = {
    videos:[
      {id:1,name:"VIDEO_ONE"},
      {id:2,name:"VIDEO_TWO"}
    ]
  };
  
  $scope.videoList = [
    {id:1,name:"VIDEO_ONE"},
    {id:2,name:"VIDEO_TWO"},
    {id:3,name:"VIDEO_Three"}
  ];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="testapp">
  <div ng-controller="appCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="singleVideo in model.videos">
      {{singleVideo.name}}
      <select ng-model="singleVideo.id" ng-options="item.id as item.name for item in videoList" ng-selected="true"></select>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: when i'm changing the value only id is changing and the name is not, do you have any idea why? "videos":[{"id":1,"name":"VIDEO_ONE"},{"id":2,"name":"VIDEO_TWO"}]

Comment: as i mentioned, it only updates the `id` attribute. i'd leave the `name` attribute out, because it is redundant, if you take the name from `videoList`.

Comment: the thing is when i'm changing item or adding another item name is not updated in the model so i need a way to include the name as well, how can i do that?

Comment: either you do it manually after event x, or you just save the id in `model.videos` and get the name from `videoList`, since you have the id. i'd suggest approach #2.

Comment: well i'm not sure if it's the best practice, basically i wanted to have them both as part of the model, not sure why that can't happen.

Comment: then you should put that logic into a `ng-change` that will additionally set the name attribute. best practice is not having redundant data, and your approach obviously has redundancy.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div data-ng-repeat="singleVideo in model.videos">
    {{singleVideo}}<select data-ng-model="singleVideo.name" ng-options="item.name as item.name for item in videoList"></select>
</div>
```